# Skipping broken jsons python

Tags: python, json

I am reading JSON from the database and parsing it using python.

```
cur1.execute("Select JSON from t1")
dataJSON = cur1.fetchall()
for row in dataJSON:
 jsonparse = json.loads(row)
```

The problem is some JSON's that I'm reading is broken.
I would like my program to skip the json if its not a valid json and if it is then go ahead and parse it. Right now my program crashes once it encounters a broken json. 
T1 has several JSON's that I'm reading one by one.

Comment: whats the exception you're getting? i'm not a python developer but i'm assuming you could wrap your jsonparse statement in a try - catch statement to do a continuation of your loop if an exception (for bad json parsing) is thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

You're getting an expecting string or buffer - you need to be using row[0] as the results will be 1-tuples... and you wish to take the first and only column.

**If you did want to check for bad json**

You can put a try/except around it:

```
for row in dataJSON:
    try:
        jsonparse = json.loads(row)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Now - instead of using `Exception` as above - use the type of exception that's occuring at the moment so that you don't capture non-json loading related errors... (It's probably `ValueError`)

Comment: Thanks.. I get a "expected string or buffer" exception

Comment: @Ankur Here's me trying `json.loads('{')` -> `ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 0 (char 0)` - So that gives you `ValueError` that'll be what you want to use instead of `Exception` - otherwise you'll be catching too many exceptions

Comment: @Ankur depending how "broken" your data is - you may also wish to consider the third party https://pypi.python.org/pypi/demjson module - which has a slightly relaxed parser, (such as names don't need to be quoted etc...), so it's possible it can sort out a few things the more strict parser can't, and then you can ignore the rest...

Comment: @ankur - just noticed you probably don't have broken json data and that it's because you're passing a tuple. See update.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to silently ignore errors, you can wrap `json.loads` in a try..except block:

```
try: jsonparse = json.loads(row)
except: pass
```

Comment: That will silently mask *all* errors - things such as `jsonparse = josn.loads(row)` will also fail...

Comment: @JonClements while I agree, you'd have to specifically check for ValueError (`except ValueError as e`).  FYI: `NameError` is also an `Exception`, so your answer suffers the same problem

Comment: My answer is a template that explains not to use `Exception` and how to find the one to use - and goes on to mention it's likely that `ValueError` is what's required... But I don't without going through the modules code, and the the OP's data, know which exceptions they're experiencing...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def f(x):
  try:
    return json.loads(x)
  except:
    pass

json_df = pd.DataFrame()
json_df = df.join(df["error"].apply(lambda x: f(x)).apply(pd.Series))
```

After JSON loads, I also wanted to convert each key-value pair from JSON to a new column (all JSON keys), so I used apply(pd.Series) in conjunction. You should try this by removing that if your goal is only to convert each row from a data frame column to JSON.